# Connecting parameterized BigQuery custom query to Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to create a parameterized custom query datasource from BigQuery to Google Data Studio project.

In Google documentation, they ask to click ADD PARAMETER below the custom query editor. 
source - https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296#parameters

But below the SQL query box, "Custom Parameters" section is empty.

How do I add custom parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is an issue with Data Studio.

I can add parameters without any issues and I didn't do anything to both Data Studio or my GCP project.

I found this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145622261) where users are reporting having this same behavior.

I suggest [starring](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) the issue and asking for help there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As of 6th Dec 2019, parameters are back!!!